# Android application is not compatible with the tablets

Tags: permissions, compatibility, tablet

These are the permissions I am using :

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.GET_TASKS
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
com.android.vending.BILLING
com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

And I have also added required attributes as false for telephony and location features:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"  android:required="false"/>
```

But still on the developer console it says your app is not compatible with the tablets.
I have also set support screens for large and xlarge as true, and am not using any of the screen compatibility fields. THANKS!!